# Responsive layout isn't working at an intermediate size. Works smaller and larger

Tags: css, responsive-design

In an 800px wide viewport, the logo in the header drops down and the nav shifts. At a slightly smaller size, it responds appropriately. At a larger size, it is also fine. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in the css to cause this.

http://smore.rvadv.com/?page_id=60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me it's the margin-left:5% on #logo. You should not mix percentage and pixel measurements like that. Stick to one of them, so in this case change 5% to an amount of pixels.